ngx-capture library not fully loaded for the first time
I am using ngx-capture library where it is not loading properly for the first time
but the subsequent time it works fine.
@if (freeze) {
<ngx-capture #ngxCapture [target]="screen" (resultImage)="saveImage($event, template)"></ngx-capture>
}

freeze: boolean = false
takeScreenshot() {
    this.freeze = !this.freeze
  }

ngx-capture is loaded in dom. when i set freeze true and vice-versa.But the drag and select option not working for the first time but the next subsequent times it works.
